# Rspec, Scope Namespaces file and folder structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have one

```
#routes.rb
scope module: "api" do
  namespace :v1 do
```

and in my rspec folder structure I have

```
spec
 └── requests
     └── v1
         └── files
```

I want to create another namespace on a different scope
so I'm changing my routes.rb to

```
scope module: "api" do
  namespace :v1 do
   ...
scope module: "another-api" do
  namespace :v1 do
```

Would this be the right path here to keep my file structure organized?

```
spec
└── requests
    ├── api
    │   └── v1
    │       └── files
    └── other-api
        └── v1
            └── files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks about right. Keeping the route definition/source files/test files in the same hierarchical structure helps developers to quickly refer a file, helps the IDE to navigate between test & source file using keyboard shortcuts.